# Error: Undefined class 'Widget'. Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

I recently started learning flutter programming and started with a practical example of firebase authentication. I downloaded the ready-made code to work from here: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps?hl=ru#0

When I opened the project in VScode, I saw 5k+ errors like "Undefined class 'Widget'. Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'Widget'." It's the same with the other base classes.

The same error is repeated in other projects.

I tried reinstalling Flutter completely and got no results.
I also tried doing `$ flutter clean` and `$ flutter pub get` in the terminal, but also got no results.

UPD:
I tried this steps and got no results too: `$ flutter packages get` -> `$ flutter packages upgrade` -> restart VScode

Trying Pub Get in VScode I recieve this error:

> Because next_gen_ui requires SDK version >=3.0.0-417.2.beta <4.0.0,
> version solving failed. pub get failed command:
> "/Users/mark/Documents/Dev/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
> __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example" pub env: {   "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/mark/Documents/Dev/flutter",
> "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",   "PUB_CACHE":
> "/Users/mark/.pub-cache", }

Comment: It's looks like VSC related, not really a Dart/Flutter problem. I edited the tags.

Comment: Is "flutter doctor -v" happy?  Does it show the VSC extension installed?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz its all okay:

[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.62.0